# TextMesh Pro InputField Character Validation using Regex

Tags: unity-game-engine

How do I go about setting the Regex string for the TextMesh Pro InputField when it has been set to use Regex?

*I have set it to use Regex using*

```
inputfield.characterValidation = TMPro.TMP_InputField.CharacterValidation.Regex;
```

But am unable to find out where to set said Regex string.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This value must be set via the Editor.
The variable you are looking for is `TMP_InputField.m_RegexValue` but it is marked private. There doesn't seem to be a set or get defined outside of the Editor functionality.

You could define a custom validator using `TMP_InputValidator` or you could hook into the `.onValidateInput` that both TMP and Unity native InputField share, as suggested on this [support thread](http://digitalnativestudios.com/forum/index.php?topic=1239.0).

Answer (score 3):

For those who need to set the input field value by script, you can use reflection to set the private variable value.

```
Type inputFieldType = Type.GetType("TMPro.TMP_InputField, Unity.TextMeshPro", true, true);
System.Reflection.FieldInfo regexValueFieldInfo = inputFieldType.GetField("m_RegexValue",System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic| System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
regexValueFieldInfo.SetValue(m_InputField, "your regex here");
```